# is there any way to strip ansible output caused by with_items

Tags: ansible

I'm new to ansible.

I have a problem when using ansible 'with_items'.

For example, the following code:

```
- assert:
    that:
      - ...
  with_items: "{{data_array_with_big_elements}}"
```

The running effect is

```
TASK [assert] ***************
ok: [10.250.15.160] => (item={......big.....body......here....}) => else_output.
```

What I want is to strip the item body to a short one.

Is there any idea to make it?

Comment: Yes there is a way! Have a look at [loop control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the info displayed by loops using the [`loop_control` attribute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops) for your task.

```yaml
- name: A looped task with controlled label
  command: /bin/true
  loop: "{{ some_list }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Whatever you like, references to {{ item.some_attribute }} possible"
```

Check the above documentation link for more examples.